# How to make shared-preferences globally available in android application?

Tags: android, caching, sharedpreferences

I want to get some key-values throughout my application, in iOS we have user-defaults, how can we make preferences behave like that i.e. accessible from any activity?

Comment: You do not have anything to do. Just use getDefaultSharedPreferences().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new shared preference file or access an existing one by calling one of these methods:

`getSharedPreferences()` — Use this if you need multiple shared preference files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter. You can call this from any Context in your app.

`getPreferences()` — Use this from an Activity if you need to use only one shared preference file for the activity. Because this retrieves a default shared preference file that belongs to the activity, you don't need to supply a name.

For example, the following code accesses the shared preferences file that's identified by the resource string R.string.preference_file_key and opens it using the private mode so the file is accessible by only your app:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can read the official guide on [Save key-value data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).